# What generates "cannot be referenced from static context" when static keyword is not used in the class?

Tags: android, static, androidx, non-static

I get the `Non-static method 'getSupportFragmentManager()' cannot be referenced from static context` error for the following code:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
.
.
.
public class MedicalInformationFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentNameProvider, ConfirmDialogFragment.ConfirmDialogListener{
.
.
.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "Entered: onCreate");
    first = true;
    if(getArguments() != null) {
        petId = getArguments().getInt(PET_ID_KEY);
        Log.d(TAG, "Pet ID is: " + petId);
        sMedicalInformationViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MedicalInformationViewModel.class);
        FragmentManager fm = FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        if(fm != null) {
            thisFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
            Log.d(TAG, "thisFragment is: " + thisFragment);
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: fm == null");
        }
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: getArguments() == null");
    }
}
.
.
.
}
```

However, the keyword 'static' is never used in the class, anywhere.

I am following the API for using [getSupportFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity?hl=en#getSupportFragmentManager()). I had used [getFragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#getFragmentManager()) but was told that `android.app.Fragment` was `deprecated in API level 28.and to use the Support Library Fragment for consistent behavior across all devices and access to Lifecycle`, but found that this `package is part of the Android support library which is no longer maintained. The support library has been superseded by AndroidX which is part of Jetpack`.

So, here I am, following what I believe are the directives of the Android API and getting an error that I don't understand. What would generate this error when the 'static' keyword is not used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling an instance method (`getSupportFragmentManager()`) on a class (`FragmentActivity`), not on an instance. The "static context" is `FragmentActivity`.

To get a `FragmentManager` for your `Fragment`, try `getParentFragmentManager()`:

```
FragmentManager fm = getParentFragmentManager();
```

If that does not seem to exist, you are on an older version of the AndroidX libraries, before that method existed. In that case, use `getFragmentManager()`:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me what generated that error message. I'm self taught and lose track of when library classes need to be instantiated and when not. For example, StringUtils is used without instantiation: StringUtils.IsEmpty(String s). In my case when I instantiate FragmentActivity and use it, the error is no more. However, using androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getParentFragmentManager is far more appropriate. Now I know what to look for, calling an instance method on a class vs an instance of it, when I get this error when I have not used the "static" keyword.

Comment: @Jeff: "For example, StringUtils is used without instantiation: StringUtils.IsEmpty(String s)" -- in the JavaDocs, that method will be marked with `static`. That means you call it on the class itself, not an instance of that class. "In my case when I instantiate FragmentActivity and use it, the error is no more" -- except that the framework, not you, should be instantiating the activity.

Comment: OK, I see that now, to look for 'static' in the documentation, I really didn't understand that until you explained it. I was developing "blind", trying things until they worked. I hate to ask such stupid questions, but sometimes I have to because they get answered well, to me, in these situations. For whatever reason everything else that I've read just didn't click. Maybe this will help someone else in the same situation, it's worth the down vote. Thanks for your time!